# Good way to losslessly compress a massive string

Tags: java, compression

I have this giant string, I was wondering if it can be compressed and if so what are some good ways to do so.

"01011311100111111112110131131011111110111011113111101101001110110110100110001001111003011011101111311102110011030111001311110113110111110111111111111111311103010001113110013100100101110000010111111111001000111111100001100030111111131113113101101001100111111100110100131001102101101110030300300011011111001111100010110011201111111011110011101011000011100013110101111003000131111012011131000000113111111311111001100111011111000101111101313111010000001131103011210111101001110010100113111311000111001100011110001000001111110001111111001010001011111100111000131000"

This is a sample and there are thousands more lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: not entirely sure if it 's something you would want, but 0000011111110000111 could become[0:5][1:7][0:4][1:3] (or similar. takes some additional functionality, but especially for large Strings like that, this could make it a lot shorter

Comment: Compression is a well-studied subject and there are plenty of libraries and tools available which does this. Asking on [so] is not a good substitute for doing research yourself.

Comment: Based on that data i would say its about the encoding. If you take 8bit per char you have 256 possible chars when you only need 0-9. Maybe try to sum up like 10 chars, convert to number and store them in a long or something. Then make a list/arry of your longs

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417632/dna-compression-using-bitset-java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest trying out-of-the-box solutions before thinking of implementing your own compression algorithm. Here you might try out `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream` and `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` if this leads to sufficiently compressed results. Only if you are unhappy with the result you might think of own schemes.