# Alternative representation of a String

Tags: java

During the run of my program i create a lot of String(1.000.000) up to size of 700 and my program eats up a lot of memory.These Strings can contain only `R,D,L,U` as chars so i thought that i could represent them differently.I thought about using BitSet but i am not sure it is more memory efficient.Any ideas?

P.S:i could also shrink the String compressing equal chars`(RRRRRRDDDD->R6D4)` but i was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Bits only have two values, 0 or 1. You will have to store four different values so bits won't work. Two bits would be necessary to represent each value.

Comment: You have to represent 4 different values, si using two bits (00, 01, 10, 11) for each caracter could be an alternative.

Comment: Maybe [EnumSet](https://www.baeldung.com/java-enumset) is suitable?

Comment: If you could just change your letters to A, C, G and T then this is a full duplicate of your question with useful answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417632/dna-compression-using-bitset-java/40418156#40418156 (and still useful if you can't because the mechanisms are the same)

Comment: Unfortunately, EnumSet as per Abra's suggestion is not suitable here because you would only be able to store at most one of each letter in it.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). As the community can provide a varied range of solutions to specific problems, can you explain what your program is trying to accomplish that needs the creation of so many large strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a first step, you could try to switch to `char[]`. Java `String` takes approx 40 bytes more than the sum of its characters ([source](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077496/java-tip-130--do-you-know-your-data-size-.html)) and `char[]` is considerably more convenient than bit arithmetic

even more economical is `byte[]` since one `char` requires two bytes allocation, while a `byte` is, of course, one byte (and still has room for 256 distinct values)